# What does “If you were a chicken, you would be impeccable”

Tags: word-play, pun

I found this in pickup lines but I am not sure what exactly means , I was looking in the net but could not find exact definition or synonym? Can you help me with the meaning usage of this?

Comment: Chickens do the pecking. Hence, imPECKable. Ba dum tss.

Comment: can we say it is synonym of another unknown for sure to me phrase - girl are a beaver cause dam ?

Comment: Just wonder what the success score is when using that line...

Answer (score 1):

As @shin said, chickens *peck*, so that’s where the wordplay comes in: “Pecking” means something like poking around with one’s beak in order to eat food. “Impeccable” means “perfect”/“flawless”. So you’re basically saying that the person you’re talking to is perfect, or if they interpret it literally, like a perfect chicken. I would assume that the person on the receiving end of this line would find it corny  [no pun intended, since chickens are known to eat corn].